# Pandas: Divide values in one dataframe by corresponding values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two pandas dataframes:

```
d1 = {'year': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'val1': [3, 6, 9, 12]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)


   year val1
0   1    3
1   2    6
2   1    9
3   2    12
```

and

```
d2 = {'year': [1, 2], 'val2': [3, 6]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)


   year val2
0   1    3
1   2    6
```

I would like to divide the two values of `val1` for a given `year` by the value of `val2` for the same `year`. So the output should look like this:

```
   year val1
0   1    1
1   2    1
2   1    3
3   2    2
```

An easy way to do this is with a for loop but I would prefer to have a non-loop solution. I tried different combinations of `groupby`, `apply`, and `map` without much success.

Here is the for loop solution:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('year')
df3 = df1.copy()
for t in [1, 2]:
    idx = df1['year'] == t
    df3.loc[idx, 'val1'] = df1.loc[idx, 'val1'].divide(df2.loc[t].item())
```

Comment: Merge on year then divide columns by columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `map`:

```
df1['val1'] /= df1['year'].map(df2.set_index('year')['val2'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   year  val1
0     1   1.0
1     2   1.0
2     1   3.0
3     2   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` and `eval`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='year', how='left', sort=False)
    .eval('val1=val1/val2')
 )
```

Output:

```
   year  val1  val2
0     1   1.0     3
1     2   1.0     6
2     1   3.0     3
3     2   2.0     6
```

Or performing an in place modification of `df1`:

*NB. `how='left', sort=False` is critical for this solution!*

```
df1['val1'] /= df1.merge(df2, on='year', how='left', sort=False)['val2']
```

Output:

```
   year  val1
0     1   1.0
1     2   1.0
2     1   3.0
3     2   2.0
```

Comment: Wow, `eval` is cool! It takes the place of an ugly `.pipe(lambda x: x.assign(val1=x.val1/x.val2))` :)

Comment: But, this doesn't preserve the order of `df1`.

Comment: @richardec but it is also slower, use sparingly ;)

Comment: @richardec also fixed the order (which made me think of another solution) ;)

Comment: Don't worry, this wasn't the goal :p (already upvoted yours)

Comment: Ty! :) (Sorry for not upvoting your comments in reply...I guess I use SO too much! I haven't any more comment votes :D)